# Wordpress javascript parameters removed in Visual editor of posts

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I use WordPress 4.5.3. I want to add the following script to my post:

```
   <script src='/free/load.js' lang='en' size='p' kind='m'></script>
```

I add the script when I am on the "Text" tab on the Edit a post page. When I go to the Visual tab and then back to the Text tab, the last part of the script is removed and it looks like this:

```
   <script src='/free/load.js'></script>
```

Sometimes the parameters passed to the script may need to be changed, so I cannot allow to have them removed.

I read that in WordPress 2 there is an option to disable Rich editor, however in 4.5.3 I see only the option "Disable the visual editor when writing" under User's Profile options. This removes the whole Visual editor which I do not want.

Answer (score 0):

Probably better to create yourself a shortcode that loads the js file with the parameters passed to the shortcode tag.

Or if the script is in every post add custom fields to the post for the script params. Little more user friendly as well.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API